# How to get input dataset from Look up transformation in ssis

Tags: ssis

i have an flat file input dataset, and i need to use look up transformation for comparing 3 columns with that of input to reference dataset used in look up transformation.

After look up operation operation is performed i need to get the input columns also along with reference dataset columns.

I googled but i coluldn't find any method to get input dataset from look up. The only solution left is Merge join. I dont want to use merge Join

Comment: hi, I didn't understand you problem. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

The input columns are automatically added to the output pipelines of a Lookup transformation. You'll be able to reference them in subsequent transformations.

Comment: They are not. You can bring back 50 columns (SELECT * FROM REF_TABLE) and *none* will be automatically added to the dataflow for 2008 - 2012. They will be listed on the Available Columns section but they will not be available to downstream transformations unless explicitly added. I don't have a 2005 installation handy to verify abut I don't recall that being the case there either

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning the columns from the input dataset, not from the Lookup data. For the Lookup, any columns to be included must be added explicitly as you say. However, for the input data, all columns always get passed down, as there is nowhere to select them.